# How create portable version application?

Tags: c++, portability

How can I create portable version for my application?  My application similar to Power Point. I have developed it using C++.
Thanks.

Comment: Portable to what, and in what way?  Something you can recompile for several platforms?  And, if so, which platforms?

Answer (score 1):

I think the questioner might talk about portable application, as being able to simply copy whole application to a pendrive and use it on another computer. You should eliminate any dependencies on registry. If you use dynamic libraries, you should distribute it with your application. You should store all files in the same library with your application. You shouldn't do anything what needs elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about platform/compiler portability take a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/C++_Portability_Guide).